# Getting AJAX HTTP 500 in SpringMVC response

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the list of users from Mongodb with ajax it works without ajax. I did this with MySQL and it worked so I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

I can send the request and go to the method and return the `List<User>`.
But when I put it in map can't get that map as a response in the success function.

My Console Output:

```html
free.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null
    at window.onmessage (free.js:31)
window.onmessage @ free.js:31
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/UserManagementMongoDB/list 500
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
load @ submitedform:342
onload @ submitedform:25
submitedform:355 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at Object.error (submitedform:355)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Here is my Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String,Object> getAll(User user) {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        List<User> list = mainPageService.getAllUsers();

        if (list != null){
            map.put("status","200");
            map.put("message","Data found");
            map.put("data", list);
        }else{
            map.put("status","404");
            map.put("message","Data not found");

        }

    return map;
}
```

And my ajax load function

```
data = "";
load = function(){  
    $.ajax({
        url:'list',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
            alert("Hello");
                data = response.data;
                $('.tr').remove();
                for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){                  
                    $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> "+response.data[i].userName+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].userSurname+" </td> <td> <a href='#' onclick= edit("+i+");> Edit </a>  </td> </td> <td> <a href='#' onclick='delete_("+response.data[i].userId+");'> Delete </a>  </td> </tr>");

                }           
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(response);    
          }

    });
```

Here is my dependencies

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>UserManagementMongoDB</groupId>
  <artifactId>UserManagementMongoDB</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>UserManagementMongoDB Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  <!-- Servlet Library -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.data.commons.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
 </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.tanesha.recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
 <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
 <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
    
</dependencies>



  <!-- Properties for the dependencies -->
  <properties>
  
  <java-version>1.7</java-version>
   <!-- Spring properties -->
   
   <spring.framework.version>5.0.9.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
   <spring.data.commons.version>1.12.1.RELEASE</spring.data.commons.version>
   <spring.data.mongodb.version>1.10.6.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>
   
   <!-- Other properties -->
   <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
   <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
   <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
  </properties>
  
  <build>
    <finalName>ExampleWebApplication</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am getting 500 right now I just can't get the response everything other than that works. I can send my parameters with ajax just can't receive the map resources

My model code:

```html
public class User {

@Id
private String userId;

private String userName;
private String userSurname;
private String phoneNo;

public User(String userId,String userName,String userSurname,String phoneNo) {
    setUserId(userId);
    setUserName(userName);
    setUserSurname(userSurname);
    setPhoneNo(phoneNo);
}


public User() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getUserSurname() {
    return userSurname;
}
public void setUserSurname(String userSurname) {
    this.userSurname = userSurname;
}
public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}
public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}
```

My Stacktrace:

> ava.lang.Exception
>       at com.kaan.springmvc.controller.MainPageController.getAll(MainPageController.java:117)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Blockquote

Comment: If you are getting a 500, then there must be a server side error message. Adding this to the question would help.

Comment: I am editing it. Thank you for the advice

Comment: please share stacktrace

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Added the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Do you separate the front end and back end?

If yes, it might be different server or port number and violate CORS. Please help to update more information.

The second point, your method require User object, but i don't any thing relative to it from ajax request?

Comment: I am not sure about what seperating them means. I just have model service and controller and passing data to and from the view page.

User object is in a model package it just has id name surname.

Comment: Not so much information, Can you post more about model package? Do your server receive any request from ajax request? And how is the status? 404 or 400?

Comment: I added the codes in the question. I am getting HTTP 500 and i can't get data i just can send it through ajax. It works with Jquery but not with ajax.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, it seem your setting is wrong somewhere and web context can't start normally. The log of server will help to discover something

Comment: I can share my servlet and context aswell if it helps.But i am kind of new at SpringMVC so i don't exactly know how to write or get logs.